# Значение строки : if(!(i%j)) break;

Tags: c++

Затруднения с данной строкой `if(!(i%j)) break;`.
Нашел то, что данное выражение равно `(i%j)==0`.

*Вопрос:*
почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (             Если
    !            Не
    (i%j)        i при делении на j дает ненулевой остаток
 ) break;        закончить цикл
```

Т.е. - закончить цикла, когда `i` делится на `j`...

Answer (score 0):

Знак процента это остаток от деления. У вас (i%j)==0 буквально значит что значение i нацело делиться на j. Как 4/2=0. Добавьте это в условие и получите : если i/j=0 то break;  восклицательный Знак же значит -не истину те не делиться i нацело на j